# R function to rename image files

Tags: r, file-rename

I am trying to write a code to rename some image files that I have. All the image files from 115 to 263 I would like to rename by adding a +1 to the number. My files always have two parts "brain-number". I would like to keep the brain and just change the number.

This is my code so far:

```r
# Define a vector of image numbers to rename

image_numbers <- c(1:263)

# Loop through each brain subfolder

for (brain_folder in list.files(path)) {
brain_path <- file.path(path, brain_folder)

# Loop through each subfolder

for (subfolder in list.files(brain_path)) {
subfolder_path <- file.path(brain_path, subfolder)

    # Loop through each image file
    for (i in seq_along(list.files(subfolder_path))) {
      filename <- list.files(subfolder_path)[i]
      
      # Extract the position and image number from the filename
      parts <- strsplit(filename, "-")[[1]]
      position <- parts[1]
      image_number <- parts [2]
      
    
        
        # Check if the image number is greater than or equal to 115
        if (image_number >= 115) {
          new_image_number <- image_number + 1
          new_filename <- paste0(position, "-", new_image_number, ".tif")
          file.rename(file.path(subfolder_path, filename), file.path(subfolder_path, new_filename))
        }
      }
    }

}
```

I am getting the warning message:

```
Error in image_number + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Could anyone help me? I have been struggling with making this code since weeks and it never works the way I want it to. My goal is to basically skip the number 115 in my image file names because in the end I need to assign Image 1 to 115.

Comment: Currently, image_number is stored as character so you could not do numerical operation. Try ```image_number <- as.numeric(parts[2])```

Comment: You do not have to iterate, etc: within `list.files` use the argument `recursive = TRUE` and that will list all the subfolders within the folder. Also invoke `full.names = TRUE`. It also seems that you are interested in files which has image number > 115. You can select only these files within `list.file` using the `pattern` argument. Then you can use `file.rename`. In all these steps, no iteration since everything is vectorized